# What file format do we need to upload variables through the admin in airflow?

Tags: airflow

I'm trying to define a variable file to upload through the airflow UI and I'm struggling to find the correct format to upload.

I've created a file called settings.cfg that looks like:

```
my_var=test
```

However when I try to upload this through the Airflow Admin->Variables dialog I get the following message:

```
Missing file or syntax error.
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It expects JSON.

```
{
  "my_var": "test",
  "your_var": "hello"
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/1.8.2/airflow/www/views.py#L1766-L1779